# How to replace 1's in each column with a different value using a lookup table in r

Tags: indexing, replace

I would like to replace "1" in each column with a different value depending on the column.

df

```
SNP1 SNP2 SNP3
1 2 1
2 1 0
1 0 1
```

key

```
SNP1 SNP2 SNP3
5 6 7
```

desired output

```
SNP1 SNP2 SNP3
5 2 7
2 6 0
5 0 7
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

edit: my key file has columns in a different order, and missing some.
key

```
SNP3 SNP1
7 5
```

Tim Biegeleisen answer if fine, but requires key to have columns in same order. Is it possible to match the columns in df and key, and then replace the 1 in df with the value from key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` here.  `mapply` is a good candidate because it lets us iterate over each pair of columns in the two data frames at the same time.

```
fun <- function(v1, v2) {
    v1[v1 == 1] = v2[1]
    return(v1)
}
df <- mapply(fun, df, key)

df
     SNP1 SNP2 SNP3
[1,]    5    2    7
[2,]    2    6    0
[3,]    5    0    7
```

### Demo

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the quick answer.  Just needed to replace test with fun in the mapply line.